# Serilog build error - Indexed source information could not be retrieved

Tags: c#, visual-studio, serilog

I am using nuget Serilog 2.7.1 in my project in visual studio 2017. Locally while building project it build successfully, but on build server it is giving me error -

Indexed source information could not be retrieved from E:\Builds\21\ProjectName\Binaries\Project1\Serilog.pdb. Error: Symbol indexes could not be retrieved.

Project is partially successful with above error. It seems that logging is working without any issue with this build, but I want to remove above error.

Please let me know what is resolution of this.

Comment: Doubt that's anything to do with serilog - hundreds of thousands of devs have just done what you have. Do a backup and then `git clean -fdx` to force VS to redownload/rebuild everything locally

Comment: On local machine everything is working fine. I am getting this error on build server. So anything I have to do on build server?

Comment: build servers can typically be configured to do a hard clean before a build, which can likely get you to a position where you won't see environmental issues like this. However, this is more a build server question and you havent mentioned which one etc. Typically asking others that might have had similar issues and/or search for the main error message with the name of the build server might help